# problem ajaxurl - designthemes-core-features

Tags: errors

I have a problem with ajaxurl, I would like to know how I could fix this error code js "not defined" by designthemes-core-features.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.dt-plugin-notice .notice-dismiss', function() {

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl, 
            data: {
                action: 'dt_plugin_dismiss_notice'
            }
        });

    });

});
```

Nota:
is the plugin of a theme, this code can be found in the admin.js file inside the JS folder.
The code "url: ajaxurl," (says: "ajaxurl is not defined")
Would there be any idea?
Would you like some more information?
Thank you

Comment: See [this code snippet](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/#comment-1391) and implement in your theme/child theme. As you din't provide much information about where the code is, we cannot provide any to-the-point solution to your issue.

Comment: What exactly is not defined? You need to be more specific.

Comment: is the "designthemes-core-features" plugin of a theme, this code can be found in the admin.js file inside the JS folder. The code "url: ajaxurl," (says: "ajaxurl is not defined") Would there be any idea? Would you like some more information? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

is the "designthemes-core-features" plugin of a theme, this code can be found in the admin.js file inside the JS folder.
The code "`url: ajaxurl`," (says: "ajaxurl is not defined")
Would there be any idea?
Would you like some more information?
Thank you

Answer (score -3):

Please try

```
dttheme_urls.ajaxurl
```

Comment: Can you please explain what this should fix and why? As is, this answer is not helpful for the OP nor for the rest of the website...

Comment: es el complemento "designthemes-core-features" de un tema, este código se puede encontrar en el archivo admin.js dentro de la carpeta JS. El código " url: ajaxurl," (dice: "ajaxurl no está definido") ¿Hubiera alguna idea? ¿Quieres más información? Gracias